# Gson doesn't get the full string value

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, gson

I want to get the value of the key `"FullName"` from this json response:

```
{
    "Succeeded": true,
    "DebugError": "",
    "SystemUser": {
        "ID": 94,
         "FullName": "John Smith",
        "Email": "abcd@gmail.com",
        "PhoneNumber": "0000000000",
        "Country": "USA"
    } 
}
```

Inside the `onResponse` method I did this:

```
// code..

  @Override
  public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {  
    Gson gson = new Gson();               
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(response.getJSONObject("SystemUser").get("FullName").toString()));
    reader.setLenient(true);
    String name = gson.fromJson(reader, String.class);

    Log.i(  " name: ", name + "");
    // I tried to use    getString("FullName")   but shows the same result.

  }

// code..
```

---

The value in Logcat is => **`name: John`**

Why didn't print the full name (John Smith) ??

Comment: On your model use '/' for string reading e.g. "SystemUser{"+"FullName="+ FullName+ '\''+
                "ID="+ ID+ .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than proceeding this way you can go for a better approach. Most of the apps have complex json structures, for which this kinda approach is not advisable.

Create a model class by copy pasting your sample json to [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). Now select Target language:`Java` , Annotation style: `Gson`

Download or copy paste the generated model class and use the following (Assuming your class name as `UserDetails`).

```
UserDetails userDetails = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), UserDetails.class);
```

Now you have the model class populated with all the values. Retrieve which ever you want.

**NOTE:** *Variable names and inner class names should be exactly same as the JSON structure. Better use annotation. Or else the model class will not get populated correctly*

Comment: I'm using the model approach for all my other requests, but I figured in this case I only want just one value so a whole class model won't be necessary.!?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your GSON implementation is redundant. Just use

```
response.getJSONObject("SystemUser").getString("FullName")
```

Comment: I added a comment in the code that says I tried this and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Confirm your JSON response logging `response.toString()`. It looks like the response is different.